# Http/GraphRawResponse.php while login with facebook using codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter-3, facebook-login

config/facebook.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['facebook_app_id']              = '*************';
$config['facebook_app_secret']          = '*******************';
$config['facebook_login_type']          = 'web';
$config['facebook_login_redirect_url']  = 'login';
$config['facebook_logout_redirect_url'] = 'logout';
$config['facebook_permissions']         = array('email');
$config['facebook_graph_version']       = 'v2.10';
$config['facebook_auth_on_load']        = TRUE;
```

controller

```
public function login()
{
    $userData = array();
    if($this->facebook->is_authenticated())
    {
        $fbUserProfile = $this->facebook->request('get', '/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender');
        $userData['oauth_provider'] = 'facebook';
        $userData['oauth_uid'] = $fbUserProfile['id'];
        $userData['name'] = $fbUserProfile['first_name'].' '.$fbUserProfile['last_name'];
        $userData['email'] = $fbUserProfile['email'];
        $userData['gender'] = $fbUserProfile['gender'];
        $userID = $this->user->checkUser($userData);
        if(!empty($userID)){
            $data['userData'] = $userData;
            $this->session->set_userdata('userData',$userData);
        }else{
           $data['userData'] = array();
        }
        $data['logoutURL'] = $this->facebook->logout_url();
    }
    else
    {
        $data['authURL'] =  $this->facebook->login_url();
    }
    $this->load->view('login',$data);
}
```

view: login.php

```
<?php
    if(!empty($authURL)) 
    {
        echo '<a href="'.$authURL.'"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign in with facebook</a>';
    }
    else
    {
?>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p><b>Facebook ID : </b><?php echo $userData['oauth_uid']; ?></p>
            <p><b>Name : </b><?php echo $userData['name']; ?></p>
            <p><b>Email : </b><?php echo $userData['email']; ?></p>
            <p><b>Gender : </b><?php echo $userData['gender']; ?></p>
            <p><b>Logout from <a href="<?php echo $logoutURL; ?>">Facebook</a></b></p>
        </div>
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

I am simply create facebook login and I have add `config/facebook.php` and library of facebook sdk `libraries/facebook-php-sdk` but when I click on facebook image login it redirect me on facebook login after return back it show an error i.e. `Http/GraphRawResponse.php` I have no idea about that. Please help me to solve this.

Thank You

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: Http/GraphRawResponse.php

Line Number: 108

Comment: Something seems to go wrong with parsing a response header here - hard to tell what exactly from the outside though, this will need some local debugging.